# Bulk permissioning of Team Drives

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script, permissions, google-drive-sharing, google-shared-drive

I've been looking through the documentation but am coming up empty handed.

How can I assign permissions in bulk across multiple team drives?  For instance, a new hire needs to be given Commenter permission to 30 team drives.  Or a new external associate not in the organization needs to be given said permissions.  It's very time consuming to go to the team drive, manually enter or select the e-mail address, then select the permissions, possibly click to confirm if it's outside the organization, then repeat *thirty times*.

Likewise, if an employee leaves the organization or otherwise needs to be removed from 30 Team Drives.  Not only is it time consuming, but error prone.  What if a drive gets missed?  Now they still have access when they shouldn't, and it's likely nobody will notice for months.

How can Team Drive permissions be changed en mass?

Answer (score 1):

> How can Team Drive permissions be changed en mass?

Use the Google Drive API. For this you could create an app by using programming languages that are able to work with REST APIs or to use the Google Drive Advanced Service of Google Apps Script.